# woocommerce products shortcode with limit property not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am using woocommerce product shortcode for feching product list

```
echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="4" columns="4" orderby="popularity" ]' );
```

and referring it from [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/).

Columns and orderby property works fine but limit is not working.
I always return list of all the product.

How can i fix this?

Comment: why it is down voted ?

Comment: I increased your rating bro

Comment: @NikitaDudarev thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using a WooCommerce version below 3.1.

Using

```
[best_selling_products]
```

instead of

```
[products orderby="popularity" ]
```

should work.

This is WooCommerce's word on the matter: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/3-1-earlier/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because none of your product was purchased. Try making a test purchase of several products. Or change `popularity` to `title` or to another. Read more information on that [site](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6)

```
echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="4" columns="4" orderby="title" ]' );
```

or

```
echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="4" columns="4" orderby="id" ]' );
```

Comment: i had tried `[products limit="4" columns="4" ]` but it always return me list of all the product

Comment: @ParitoshMahale `echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="4" columns="4" orderby="id" ]' );` try this

Comment: @ParitoshMahale hmmm, how many products you have? and how many products display on page with this filter limit="4"

Comment: i have total 36 product and it showing all 36 in list

Comment: @ParitoshMahale Create a new page through the admin panel and insert only shortcode `[products limit="4" columns="4" orderby="id" ]`

Comment: created new page and added shortcode only but still same result :(

Comment: @ParitoshMahale sorry I tried help you but, I don't see your site and code

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the quotes. Use these: `"3"` instead of `”3”` or `″3″`